# Cakephp nested contain

Tags: cakephp, containable

I have tree model with this structures and tables:

```
Rate:
id, model_name, object_id
1 , SocialPost, 12
public $belongsTo => array(
                'SocialPost' => array(
                    'className' => 'Social.SocialPost',
                    'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Rate.object_id = SocialPost.id',
                    ),
                )
            )
```

SocialPost:
id, file_id

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'File' => array(
        'className' => 'File',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array(
            'File.id = SocialPost.file_id',
        ),
    ),
);
```

File:
id, title

---

all tree models actsAs containable

this code work nice in SocialPostsController:

```
$posts = $this->SocialPost->find('all', array(
        'limit' => 5,
        'contain' => array(
            'File'
        )

    ));
```

output: http://pastie.org/private/9ixxufncwlr3tofgp8ozw

but this code in RatesController return same file for all SocialPost:

```
$mostRated = $this->Rate->find('all', array(
        'limit' => $count,
        'contain' => array(
            'SocialPost' => array(
                'File'
            )
        )

    ));
```

output: http://pastie.org/private/lbqryo1gxgvxjb5omfwrw

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think your associations should all be belongsTo:

```
class Rate extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'SocialPost' => array(
      'className' => 'Social.SocialPost',
      'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
    )
  );
}

class SocialPost extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'File'
  );
}
```

And then your find command can look like:

```
$mostRated = $this->Rate->find('all', array(
  'limit' => $count,
  'contain' => array(
    'SocialPost.File'
  )
));
```

Also, I would double-check that your `'className' => 'Social.SocialPost'` is correct. This means that the `SocialPost` model exists in a plugin called `Social`.

Comment: Social is plugin and SocialPost is its model.
I cannot use belongsTo for File in SocialPost.because of every post has one file and in File model I have belongsTo for SocialPost.every file belongs to many SocialPost.